# bash does not show prompt (prompt missing)

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a server that does not show standard bash prompt, after I log out from the machine.

If I ssh to this server, I can do all operation there (e.g. ls, cwd, etc)
Tried to reinstall bash (sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash) also did not help, as well as source the bashrc.

This is the output that I currently have after ssh:

```
Linux mymachine 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
source ~/.bashrc
ls
cd /tmp/
ls
192525856
250675275
873713638
```

(no prompt shown there, but I can type any linux command there and directly shown ).

how can i have the bash prompt shown again?

Edit:
With this command, my bash prompt comes back again

```
bash -i
bash: cannot set terminal process group (4896): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
mymachine@myuser2:~$ ls
```

now I am trying to figure out the error above, and why it returns me the prompt despite error.

Comment: Most probably your environment variable `PS1` is set to an empty string. Check your sourced files where this is set.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, don't just edit your question. This will mark your question as "solved" in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found the issue, the /dev/pts is missing for some reason. After mounting everything, it works as expected:

```
mount -t devtmpfs -o mode=0755 udev /dev
mount: udev is already mounted or /dev busy
       udev is already mounted on /dev
       udev is already mounted on /opt/axess_310_TICKET/dev
       udev is already mounted on /opt/grafana_test/dev
       udev is already mounted on /opt/axess_39/dev
       udev is already mounted on /opt/axess_39_TICKET/dev
       udev is already mounted on /opt/ACS_DUMP_TEST/dev

mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
udevadm trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with using SLURM's srun and forgetting the pty option:

```
srun --partion=my_partion bash
```

causes the issue. But including --pty eliminates it:

```
srun --pty --partion=my_partion bash
```

yields a promt:

```
yoder@mgmt:~$ srun --pty --partition=my_partion bash
yoder@node1:~$
```